# My degree was removed as on option at my college

Tags: texas, school

I attended Our Lady of the Lake Universery in San Antonio, TX and was seeking an RN-BSN degree. I took a year off when I had a baby but when I returned, I found out that my degree was no longer offered. They told me they allowed everyone to finish but since I was technically not enrolled at the time, I would not be given this option. They advised me to utilize their sister school in Kansas through their online program. I was accepted and told the classes I took at OLLU would be accepted as part of my GPA but would not count toward my degree. So basically I had to start all over. I enrolled at UT Arlington and received the same response. I have over $13k in student loans from OLLU and nothing to show for it. Can I get these loans discharged?

Answer (score 3):

Student loans that cover tuition and other educational expenses are for the charges that you incur by being enrolled. There may be some relationship between being enrolled and a career goal such as a degree or a job, but what you bought was the right to be in a class. You do in fact have something to show for the fees paid.

Your issue is mainly with the university and not with the agency that lent you the money. The lender does not purport that you will receive a degree, so they have not been engaged in any wrong-doing. The prospects for suing the university to force them to let you complete the degree program are slightly better but still negligible. It is only technically possible to repudiate a student loan via [bankruptcy](https://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/student-loan-debt-bankruptcy.html), if you can prove that repaying the loan would impose an undue hardship on you (and you still have to go through the bankruptcy process).

Comment: It sounds as if the quality of the classes was severely lacking, as evidenced by (a) other schools' refusal to consider the completed classes as equivalent and (b) shutdown of the program.  OP might want to demand a refund from the original school on that basis.

Comment: It appears that they are not accredited for nursing, strongly suggesting that there were problems in the past. It would at least be worthwhile to talk to a lawyer, though it's not illegal to have an unaccredited program so the question is whether they materially misrepresented the program.

Comment: There is federal legislation discharging student loans in certain cases mostly involving abusive for profit higher educational institutions that received federal assistance, and abusive lender practices. A major settlement was reached recently in one of those cases. But it isn't clear if these laws would apply in this case.